# Is Python list a valid sublist

Tags: python, sublist

I've found several questions which address variations on this problem, but none that addresses my specific question. In python, how do you determine if a list is a sublist of another list, such that each member of the sublist can be mapped to a unique member of the parent list without regard to order? This question is specific to lists, not sets, so duplicate values are allowed. (If a duplication exists in the sublist, it must also exist in the parent list of course.) I can think of several approaches to this. For example (off the top, untested):

```
def is_valid_sub(parent, sub):
    p_copy = copy.copy(parent)
    for s in sub:
        if s not in p_copy:
            return False
        p_copy.remove(s)
    return True
```

That requires making a copy of the parent list, which is memory and cpu inefficient if parent is not trivial. Another approach would be to keep track of the index of matched items, and if a match has previously occurred, check if another match occurs in the slice from the next item to the end of the list. This would need to be recursive, to allow for more than two of an item in the subset. Other approaches are similarly convoluted and cumbersome. Is there an elegant, efficient way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like you should use a counter. That's O(n).

Answer (score 0):

This script doesn't create copy of array, about time complexity cannot say.

```
def my_valid(parent,sub):
    indexes = set(x for x in range(0,len(parent)))
    arr = []
    for el in sub:
        for i in indexes:
            if el == parent[i]:
                arr.append(1)
                indexes.remove(i)
                break
                
    return len(arr) == len(sub)
```